# How to run .run files in ubuntu

Tags: executable

I download a software from http://qt-project.org/downloads and it is .run file and when I want to open that, it says:
"There is no application installed for 'executable' files.
Do you want to search for an application to open this file?"
And I click on yes but it didn't find anything.
What I have to do?!
(sorry because of my bad English :D )

Comment: What software of Qt are you trying to install? Any reason not to install the packages from Ubuntu's repository? Almost all, if not all are available in the software centre.

Comment: this file: http://download.qt-project.org/official_releases/qt/5.0/5.0.2/qt-linux-opensource-5.0.2-x86_64-offline.run

Comment: I download this and now I want to use this! mostly it's important to me to learn new things in ubuntu and I want to run this .run file but I cant

Comment: Installing from source/upstream is not the best thing to learn as a new user. Please use packages to install software. And just installing libraries, is that really what you want? And if you do, please use the official [Canonical Qt5 PPA](https://launchpad.net/~canonical-qt5-edgers/+archive/qt5-proper).